# exim4 - email clients unable to retrieve emails

Tags: debian, email, exim

I have configured exim4 on my Debian system and I am able to send emails from the server as a user and receive emails to this user. I am also able to connect mail client such as thunderbird/bluemail and I can use these to send emails but what I am unable to do is read them.

When I use i.e my Gmail account and send email to my @example email account it reaches the server, and the mail is saved in /home/user/new directory but I do not know why but either programs can not read those emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exim is a mail transport agent.  It doesn't support [POP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol), [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) or other protocols commonly used for retrieval.  You probably need to look into installing something like [Dovecot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovecot_(software)) or some other IMAP daemon.

Some links that may be helpful.

- https://wiki.debian.org/Dovecot
- https://www.dovecot.org/
- https://blog.dskwrk.com/2015/12/09/Exim4-with-Dovecot-in-SSL-on-Debian-Jessie/

Comment: Yup indeed just found this out last night :). All now configured and works perfectly fine :) but thanks for input